# Is it possible to insert a new table using the new google docs API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

My reading of the guides and docs suggests that the google docs api v1 enable one to

- read a table cell
- insert into a table cell
- insert/delete table rows

.. but that it's not yet possible to insert a new table via the API?

Is that correct? (Whereas I gather it is possible to create a new table w/ AppsScript.)

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/tables

Comment: @Greg - thanks - that's the guide I was referring to that suggests the API enables reading and modification of existing tables, but not creation of a new one.

Comment: Seems that way. Just tried inserting a table row to a blank document (i.e. specifying the table location as `{segmentId: "", index: 0}` (and also with index=1 or 2) fails with "Invalid table start location"

Comment: @doublea Now, you got to be able to create a table to Google Document using the batchUpdate method of Docs API. You can see the official document at [here](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttablerequest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As posted above in comments by Tanaike, this is now possible, as of 6/14/2019.
See updated docs here:

https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#inserttablerequest